# android ListView question

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my android application.
If I flick up/down the ListView, which method will return my 'selected' element in my list View?  How about if I use the track ball to navigate up/down my list view, which method will return the index of my selected element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I flick up/down the ListView, which
>   method will return my 'selected'
>   element in my list View?

None will, because selection is only through the trackball/D-pad.

> How about if I use the track ball to
>   navigate up/down my list view, which
>   method will return the index of my
>   selected element?

`getSelectedItem()`, `getSelectedItemId()` (for `CursorAdapter`), and `getSelectedItemPosition()`.